# Mobile gps data ploting in google map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, pubnub

I'm trying to plot the GPS data received from mobile apps using pubnub, but the map polygon is not plotting the points in the road.

how do i plot the GPS data on the road so that the path will be meaning full.
i have attache the draw data.

[image]

Comment: We are pleased that you are using PubNub for your application but just wanted to point out to all readers that this is not within PubNub's domain. However, is a device GPS accuracy issue and there some API functionality that will [snap to roads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) for you.

Comment: Proposing my comment as answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS accuracy is up to the device's capabilities (hardware & software) and you will likely always see this jagged tracing due to some inaccuracies in detecting the device's position.

Even with [Find My iPhone app](http://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my-iphone.html) you will see the device move around on the map even when the device isn't actually moving. The same thing is at play here.

What you require is an additional framework that will *snap* your path to the roads on the map. Fortunately, there is a [Snap to Roads framework](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) provided by Google Maps Roads API.